# Kick Script discord.js v.13

Tags: discord, discord.js

I wanted to copy my Kick Command from Discord v.12, but I got the problem that I can't kick any members. You can see my error code down below.

My Code:

```js
case 'kick':
case 'Kick':

            if (!message.member.permissions.has(Discord.Permissions.FLAGS.KICK_MEMBERS)) return;
    
            let kicked = message.mentions.members.first();
            if (!kicked) return 
    
            message.guild.members(kicked).kick();
    
            const kickemb = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('RED')
                .addField(`The User`, `${message.mentions.members.first()} was kicked successfully!`)
                .setFooter(`The Kick was from ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}!`)

                message.channel.send({embeds: [kickemb]});
```

My error code:

```
C:\User\Bot v13\index.js:185
            message.guild.members(kicked).kick();
                          ^

TypeError: message.guild.members is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the correct way to get a member. `kicked` is already a `GuildMember` which means you can run `.kick()` on it:

```js
kicked.kick()
```

Answer (score 2):

`Guild#members()` (`Guild#member()`) is deprecated. Your `kicked` object is already a member, call `.kick()` on that.

```js
let kicked = message.mentions.members.first();
if (!kicked) return;

kicked.kick();

// Your code...
```

Comment: I don't think `Guild.members` was *ever* a function. `Guild.member` was however

Comment: @MrMythical it is in djs v13, for v12 it was `message.guild.member(ID)`

Answer (score 2):

```
let kicked = message.mentions.members.first();
if (!kicked) return 
kicked.kick();
```

or

```
let kicked = message.mentions.members.first();
if (!kicked) return 
message.guild.members.cache.get(kicked).kick();
```

you can use both, good coding

Comment: The second one won't work however, because the member cache is mapped by id, but `kicked` is a `GuildMember` object, meaning it will return undefined and an error like `Cannot read property 'kick' of undefined` or `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'kicked')`

Comment: You're right, I noticed. 1. It Works But.